# Ошибка при транспонировании динамического двумерного массива

Tags: c++

**Проблема**: ошибка при транспонировании динамического двумерного массива.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
---------------------------
class Array
{
public:
    Array(int ROWS,int COLS) {
        this->ROWS = ROWS;
        this->COLS = COLS;
        arr = new int*[ROWS];
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = new int[COLS];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            {
                arr[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 100;
                cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    };
------------------
    Array(const Array& other) {
        this->ROWS = other.ROWS;
        this->COLS = other.COLS;
        this->arr = new int* [other.ROWS];
        for (int i = 0; i < other.ROWS; i++)
        {
            this->arr[i] = new int[other.COLS];
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < other.ROWS; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < other.COLS; j++)
            {
                this->arr[j][i] = other.arr[i][j];
                cout << this->arr[j][i] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

private:
    int ROWS;
    int COLS;
    int **arr;
};
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    srand(time(NULL));
    Array a(2, 4);
    Array b(a);


    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, скажите какая ошибка.

Comment: Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00786A6D в По книге.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFDFDFDFD.

Comment: Во первых нет тут никакой попытки транспонирования, а есть попытка копирования. Ваш конструктор копирования не освобождает память выделенной для элементов массива, которые уже не нужны. И зачем при создании матрицы  она должна выводидся на экран

Comment: Не написал деструктор так как не был написан до конца конструктор копирования,чтобы при каждом запуске программы не ловить ошибку.А без копирования тут никак,тут просто должно быть копирование элементов столба в строку(или строки в столбец).   :)

Comment: текст ошибки из комментариев перенесите прямо в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

В конструкторе копирование вы выполнили неверное присваивание:

```
for (int i = 0; i < other.ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < other.COLS; j++)
    {
        this->arr[j][i] = other.arr[i][j]; //тут
        cout << this->arr[j][i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Получается что вы создали массив такого же размера, содержащий такие же массивы, но пытаетесь копировать массив в транспонированном виде. Если размеры строк и столбцов не равны, то конечно будет выдана ошибка доступа.

Или исправьте так, чтобы при копировании создался соответствующая память для массивов, или же исправьте индексы строк и столбцов при присваивании.

Плюс,  ваш конструктор копирования не освобождает память выделенной для элементов массива, которые уже не нужны, не говоря  о деструкторе, про которого вы вообше забыли.  Утечка памяти вас вообше не беспокоит?  И оператор присваивания нужно написать, не то при присваивании вы получите не то, что ожидали

Comment: Спасибо большое,после вашего коментария всё переосмыслил и изменил.Код уже работает без проблем )